# Exception in-background task UWP ('Value does not fall within the expected range.')

Tags: uwp, background-task

System.ArgumentException: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'
I get this exception when I change time trigger number from 15 to some other number.. I do know why..
I do not get exception when the time trigger is 15.. Why? Thanks in advance.. Here is the code..

```
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
            builder.Name = "My Background Trigger";
            builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(5, false));
            // Do not set builder.TaskEntryPoint for in-process background tasks
            // Here we register the task and work will start based on the time trigger.
            BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TimeTrigger Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger?view=winrt-19041) has a minimum value which is 15 minutes. You could not set a time interval that less than 15 minutes to the TimeTrigger. This is mentioned here: [TimeTrigger.FreshnessTime Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.background.timetrigger.freshnesstime?view=winrt-19041)